# Case expression inside a where clause - Oracle

Tags: oracle, date, case, between

I have a column of dates that has 2 different formats of data: yyyy-mm-dd and dd/mm/yyyy.
Because of that, I have to indentify the format of the date so I can convert them in the right format. My SQL query is as follows:

```
select *
from teste
where
    (CASE
        WHEN data like '%-%' THEN
            TO_DATE(data, 'yyyy-mm-dd') BETWEEN
            TO_DATE(01/01/2000, 'dd/mm/yyyy') AND 
            TO_DATE(01/01/2016, 'dd/mm/yyyy')
        ELSE
            TO_DATE(data, 'dd/mm/yyyy') BETWEEN 
            TO_DATE(01/01/2000, 'dd/mm/yyyy') AND 
            TO_DATE(01/01/2016, 'dd/mm/yyyy')
    END)
```

Running this, I get the error: 
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
*Cause:
*Action:
Erro na linha: 6 Coluna: 35.

It seems that there is a problem in the between clause. Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: Useless to mention, but now you know why you should **never** store dates as string.

Comment: The problem is: is not me who created the table nor who insert data into the DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CASE` expression returns you some value. And you should compare this value with something. You can't put whole expression inside CASE.

E.g.

```
select *
from teste
where
    CASE WHEN data like '%-%' THEN
      TO_DATE(data, 'yyyy-mm-dd') 
    ELSE
      TO_DATE(data, 'dd/mm/yyyy') 
    END 
  BETWEEN  TO_DATE(01/01/2000, 'dd/mm/yyyy') AND 
            TO_DATE(01/01/2016, 'dd/mm/yyyy')
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked! Also, I need to order the dates in a order by clause. How can I aply the same logic in this?

Comment: `ORDER BY  CASE WHEN data like '%-%' THEN
      TO_DATE(data, 'yyyy-mm-dd') 
    ELSE
      TO_DATE(data, 'dd/mm/yyyy') 
    END `